# How to remove duplicate package alias in autocreated pkgname-package.R?

Tags: r, package, lifecycle, roxygen2, r-usethis

I used `lifecycle` for the `depreciated` badge, which required me to use `usethis::use_package_doc` (I BELIEVE - this may not have been the function but I think it was). This resulted in a script `myPkgName-package.R` being created, and thus `myPkgName-package.Rd` after running `devtools::document`. The entire content of the R file are:

```
#' @keywords internal
"_PACKAGE"
## usethis namespace: start
#' @importFrom lifecycle deprecated
## usethis namespace: end
NULL
```

However the Rd file has (among other stuff):

```
\docType{package}
\name{myPkgName-package}
\alias{myPkgName}
\alias{myPkgName-package}
```

R CMD check for CRAN submission now hits a warning:

> Rd files with duplicated alias 'myPkgName': 'myPkgName-package.Rd'
> 'myPkgName.Rd'

Does anyone know how to remove the `myPkgName` alias from `myPkgName-package.R` (and therefore from `myPkgName-package.Rd`)? I've tried various approaches with [aliases](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/index-crossref.html?q=alias#aliases) in `myPkgName-package.R`, notably:

```
#' @aliases myPkgName-package
#' @aliases NULL
```

(not at the same time), and run devtools::document each time, which says

> Updating myPkgName documentation

... but nothing changes in `myPkgName-package.Rd`. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've seen a few questions about this from various package maintainers but no official generic question on here, to be a focal point when others hit this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/issues/1170) answer and related links; simply follow Jenny's reprex.